# While loop keeps on running though the condition is false

Tags: java

Ok,I have a bit of hard time here fixing this bug so before I spend another day searching,I'll just ask you guys.

```
//Core Class
static String serverAnswer = "";

public static void sendMessage(String msg){
    serverAnswer = "";
    Connection.send(msg);
    while(serverAnswer.equals(""));     <infinity loop
}

//Connection Thread
public void run() {
    while(running){
        try {
            msg = (String)in.readObject();
            Core.serverAnswer = msg;
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually the thread should wait until server response and then set the answer

so the loop should stop but I dose not stop...

I have checked the following:

- thread is running: yes
- problem is definitly a endless while loop
- `Core.serverAnswer` definitly get a string from the server.

So is there anything about `while()` I don't know or any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: *"spent another day searching i'll just ask you guys."* The debugger is your friend...

Comment: Can you show the complete code?

Comment: Where do you assign anything to `serverAnswer`?

Comment: Well, this is not an efficient use of a CPU core :)

Comment: @HyperZ Aready using debugger but till now nothing obvious enough so locate the problem

Comment: @krillgar the code shows every location where i assign to `serverAnswer` everything else just reads the value out.

Comment: @Black0ut I'm not experienced enough in multithreating and client/server communication so if u have a suggestion please tell, I always like to learn new aspects.

Comment: @Oskar yes i can show more code but i'll not poste the whole code so suggest somthing and i'll post what i have.

Comment: @erinas, sorry about it, when a program enters an infinity loop like the one in your code it will consume almost the full resources of one of your logical CPU cores, there are better ways to sync between threads, take some time to read a Java Multithreading tutorial like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm it will give you a lot of tools for dealing with threads sync scenarios.

Comment: oh ok thats a point. Thank you @Black0ut . I'll get ride of the `while` then. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you use `volatile` the JVM is free to inline the value.  In particular it is free to optimise the read entirely and never check it again.

You need to make your field `volatile`.

One way to disrupt this optimisation to make a thread safe operation.

```
while(serverAnswer.equals(""))
    Thread.yield();
```

However a better solution is to read the objects into a BlockingQueue

```
public class TextSocket implements Closeable {
    final Socket socket;
    private final BufferedReader reader;
    private final PrintWriter writer;

    public TextSocket(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
        this(new Socket(hostname, port));
    }

    public TextSocket(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public String sendAndRead(String msg) throws IOException {
        writer.println(msg);
        if (writer.checkError())
            throw new IOException("Unable to write");
        writer.flush();
        return reader.readLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

I also suggest you avoid using static fields like this.  You can implement your Connection using instance fields which would allow you to have more than one if you wish.

Comment: Thank you @Peter `volatile` fixed it for now. But i would like to know the purpose of the BlockingQueue if you don't mind explaining it and to your suggestion so as i actually know static fields are faster and i have a static access to them and as long as i have just the need on that one var isn't it better to use it as static? Because otherwise I am forced to handover a instance of `Core` to everything that works with the `serverAnswer` don't I?

Comment: @erinas You can add the object to the BlockingQueue in the reading thread, and use `queue.take()` on the consuming thread.  This will block until there is an object to read. It's also thread safe.